# Terminal based RPG

Tags: java, c++, terminal

I am looking into creating a terminal based RPG, what are the accepted and recommended methods for writing this in a cross platform way?
I'm not sure what language I will be using yet, but i will need something with the functionality to move the curser and change the foreground color.
Inspired by games like NetHack, this kind of control would be ideal, and
I want to be able to write it so i can release it for windows and unix systems.
I have used ncurses for C++ and i was wondering if there is something similar to this for use with cross platform projects.

Considering:
Java
C++
C
C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're planning on doing terminal graphics, you can write your own wrapper functions for the VT-100 terminal escape codes, which can, among other things, change the foreground and background color and move the cursor.  All you have to do is write the proper escape codes.

http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm

Also, Java is probably the simplest way to be cross-platform, although it does obviously require that th0e people running your game have the Java runtime installed.  C and C++ can be quite cross-platform as well if you write your code carefully, particularly if you don't have too many external dependencies (which shouldn't be necessary for a text-based game).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a platform-independent alternative to ncurses. Your best bet would be to use ncurses for Unix systems and [pdcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) for Windows. Since the APIs are largely the same, you hopefully won't end up with too much duplicated code - just a couple of `#ifdef`s here and there.

Comment: Won't the X11 version of pdcurses allow you to use the same library on both platforms?

Comment: @Jason Not if you want it to be terminal based (which the OP does according to the title). The X11 version will run in its own window, not the terminal.

Comment: The terminal itself is typically an X11 app ... I'm not trying to be intentionally disagreeable, but I don't think there will be much of a difference in the "appearance" of the app unless he wants to run the game in the actual text-only terminal mode on Linux/Unix.

Comment: @Jason If I type the name of the application into my terminal and a new window opens, then it can hardly be called a terminal application. Semantics aside you lose functionality by using X11: 1. You actually need X11 to run. 2. You can't run it in screen (which means you can't survive X-Server restarts and more importantly you can't quickly switch between it and your other terminal apps - similarly you also can't run it in a tab of your terminal and switch between those)...

Comment: ...  3., the one that probably matters most, you can't play it over ssh or telnet (which is the foundation of MUDs and a very popular feature for nethack). 4. It won't automatically use the same fonts and other settings your terminal uses. 5. You (probably) can't set a background image or transparent background like you can with most terminals.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to look into the [PDCurses library](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) ... it supports a number of different platforms.